# Eclipse RCP: move createPartControl into background

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am using RCP for a while now and I want to open an editor in the background with the possibility to abort and to do something in the meantime.
The `Composite` created by `createPartControl` can be quite large.

But so far I could not find anything that helps doing that.
I tried out the `WorkspaceJob` in Eclipse-RCP, but then I got `Invalid thread access`.
After that I tried the `UIJob`. This one does not throw an exception but still blocks the UI from using it differently and there is no possibility to abort the Job (`runInUIThread`).

I thought there has to be a way to initialize the `Composite` in the background and then do the drawing synchronized with the `UIThread`.
But so far I could not find anything suitable for that.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Everything that creates UI components like `Composite` must be run in the UI thread so you can't do this.

Eclipse expects `createPartControl` to run quickly, if you have anything to do which does not involve creating UI objects you could run those parts in a `Job`.